# Lebesgue integral of ${x^2}$

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am having trouble calculating the Lebesgue integral of ${x^2}$ over ${]0,1]}$. I followed the instructions from my college lessons and constructed a sequence ${f_n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n*2^n}\frac{k-1}{2^n}*\chi{}_{A_{n,k}}$ with ${A_{n,k}:=\{ \sqrt{\frac{k-1}{2^n}} \leq x < \sqrt{\frac{k}{2^n}} \}}$.
${\lambda(f)}$ is equal to ${sup_{n\in N}\lambda(f_n)}$, so I calculated $\lambda(f_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n*2^n}\frac{k-1}{2^n} * (\sqrt{\frac{k}{2^n}} - \sqrt{\frac{k-1}{2^n}})$. However, I don't see how this is going to be equal to ${\frac{1}{3}}$, which would be the result of a Riemann integral. Can anyone spot a mistake or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Dissociativy+Index-Shift might be your first steps

Comment: The upper index would be $2^n$. You could work with this sum by multiplying and dividing the term in parentheses by the conjugate but an easier route is given below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using $A_{n,k}:=\left\{ \frac{k-1}{2^n} \leq x < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\}$ and

$$f_n = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \left(\frac{k-1}{2^n}\right)^2 \chi_{ A_{n,k}}$$

Since $f_n \leqslant f_{n+1}$ and $f_n(x) \to f(x) =x^2$ pointwise for $x \in [0,1]$, we have by the monotone convergence theorem,

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx  = \int_{[0,1]} f &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} f_n \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{(k-1)^2}{2^{2n}} \left(\frac{k}{2^n} - \frac{k-1}{2^n} \right) \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{3n}}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} k^2 \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n(2^{n}-1)(2\cdot 2^n -1)}{2^{3n}\cdot 6} \\ &= \frac{1}{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for the answer. However, I cannot comprehend how you calculated the new set A and the first factor of the sum. Is it some kind of "know-where-you-want-to-end-up"-magic? Because now, I am stuck at Lebesgue-integrating exp(x^3) and have the same problem again...

Comment: It is less knowing in advance and more that there are a number of options to work with. As per the definition,  Lebesgue integral is a supremum over integrals of simple functions. However, step functions are also simple functions. All I did here was exploit the fact that a Riemann integrable function (on a bounded interval) must be Lebesgue integrable.  The sequence I constructed just uses step functions whose integrals are lower Riemann sums -- which must converge to the integral. In general use any sequence you can find with a computable limit  where ...

Comment: ... conditions are met to satisfy one of the theorems, i.e. monotone convergence, dominated convergence, etc. that guarantee convergence to the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: As I said for Riemann integrable functions, you can compute the Lebesgue integral on a bounded interval as the limit of the sequence of integrals of step functions $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\,\inf_{x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]} f(x)\,\right) \chi_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}$ -- i.e, the lower Riemann sums.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374387/148510) is an example for $e^x$.  Unfortunately $e^{x^3}$ will be a problem as it has no elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks again for the replies. I think I might have misunderstood the theorem of dominated convergence, ${e^x^3}$  was just what sequence of functions in my problem converges to. I've proven that this sequence is dominated by ${3e}$, now I thought all use of finding the dominating function was that it allowed me to switch the ${lim}$ in- and outside of the Integral (${\int lim f_n = lim \int fn}$), is that correct?

Comment: @NotAName:  Are you just trying to prove that $e^{x^3}$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[0,1]$ or are you hoping to compute it as the limit of some sequence $\int_0^1 f_n$ where you can express those integrals in closed form and readily identify the limit?  Note that the integral has this [value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+e%5E(x%5E3)+from+0+to+1) -- so computing that in an elementary way would be difficult.

Comment: Clearly it is Lebesgue integrable .  That can be shown many ways: (1) it is Riemann integrable; (2) $e^{x^3} \leqslant e$ and there is a comparison test for Lebesgue integrability, (3) take $f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n e^{(k-1)^3/n^3} \chi_{\left[\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n} \right)}$ where $f_n \to f$ pointwise and apply the DCT as you suggest.

Comment: For (3) we have $|f_n(x)| \leqslant e$, a constant integrable function, so $\lim \int_{[0,1]} f_n \to  \int_{[0,1] }f$.